# Get single value from collection in DbSet and compare this value against another DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql, entity-framework-6

We are currently integrating against an external system that feeds us data. This system contains information about customer licenses and when they shall be renewed. Each license or `TPCase` as the model are called can have several renewal cycles `TPRenewalCycle`. A customer can then place an order in our system and then the license is renewed and a new renewal cycle starts.

We have however some performance problems for customers that have a lot of licenses that needs to be renewed. This is because we need to check that the next renewal cycle has not already been ordered but not processed yet, the rest of the code is fast enough (`db.OrderRows.Any(...`)

Customers can renew their licenses without using this system and because of this we would prefer to not add a nullable foreign key to `TPRenewalCycle` for `OrderRow`.

Below is our current models and code. Is there anyway to speed this process up? What I can think of would be to identify `tpCase.NextRenewalCycle` directly and then check that no value exist in `OrderRows`.

If it is hard to do in `Entity Framework` we might be willing to use `T-SQL` directly if we don't have to check it like we do now.

Case (Model from external system):

```
public class TPCase
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string BusinessSystemId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CaseId { get; set; }

    public bool VisibleToClient { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TPCaseName> CaseNames { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TPRenewalCycle> RenewalCycles { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public TPRenewalCycle NextRenewalCycle { get; set; }
}

public class TPCaseName
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string BusinessSystemId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CaseId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int NameNo { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string NameType { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BusinessSystemId,CaseId")]
    public virtual TPCase TPCase { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BusinessSystemId,NameNo")]
    public virtual TPName TPName { get; set; }

    public virtual TPNameType TPNameType { get; set; }

    public string ContactName { get; set; }
}

public class TPName
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string BusinessSystemId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int NameNo { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TPNameType
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string NameType { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class TPRenewalCycle
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("TPCase")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string BusinessSystemId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("TPCase")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CaseId { get; set; }

    public virtual TPCase TPCase { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Action { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Cycle { get; set; }

    public bool? IsOpen { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TPCaseEvent> CaseEvents { get; set; }
}

public class TPCaseEvent
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("TPRenewalCycle")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string BusinessSystemId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("TPRenewalCycle")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CaseId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    [ForeignKey("TPRenewalCycle")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Action { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
    [ForeignKey("TPRenewalCycle")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Cycle { get; set; }

    public virtual TPRenewalCycle TPRenewalCycle { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 4)]
    [ForeignKey("TPEvent")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int EventNo { get; set; }

    public virtual TPEvent TPEvent { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EventDate { get; set; }
}

public class TPEvent
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int EventNo { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
    [MaxLength]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Order (Our model):

```
public class Order
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderRow> OrderRows { get; set; }
}

public class OrderRow
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string BusinessSystemId { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CaseId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BusinessSystemId,CaseId")]
    public virtual TPCase TPCase { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Action { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Cycle { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BusinessSystemId,CaseId,Action,Cycle")]
    public virtual TPRenewalCycle TPRenewalCycle { get; set; }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

Method:

```
public IEnumerable<TPCase> GetRenewalCasesForCustomer(IList<int> customerNumberKeys)
{
    var db = new DbContext();

    var cases = db.Cases
    .Where(tpCase =>
        tpCase.VisibleToClient == true &&
        tpCase.CaseNames.Any(
             caseName => customerNumberKeys.Contains(caseName.NameNo) && 
                  caseName.BusinessSystemId == "EN" && 
                  caseName.NameType == "T") &&
        tpCase.RenewalCycles.Any(
            renewalCycle =>
            renewalCycle.IsOpen == true &&
            renewalCycle.Action == "RW" &&
            renewalCycle.CaseEvents.Any(caseEvent =>
                caseEvent.EventNo == -112 &&
                caseEvent.DueDate >= DateTime.Now
            ))
    )
    .Include(tpCase => tpCase.CaseNames.Select(caseName => caseName.TPName))
    .Include(tpCase => tpCase.CaseNames.Select(caseName => caseName.TPNameType))
    .Include(tpCase => tpCase.RenewalCycles.Select(renewalCycle => renewalCycle.CaseEvents))
    .ToList();

    foreach (var tpCase in cases)
    {
        var cycles =
          tpCase.RenewalCycles.Where(
            x => x.IsOpen == true &&
                 x.Action == "RW" &&
                 x.CaseEvents.FirstOrDefault(y => y.EventNo == -112)?.DueDate != null &&
                 x.CaseEvents.Single(y => y.EventNo == -112)?.DueDate >= DateTime.Now)
            .ToList();

        if (cycles.Any())
        {
          var cycle = cycles.OrderBy(
            x => x.CaseEvents.Single(y => y.EventNo == -11)?.DueDate)
            .First();

          tpCase.NextRenewalCycle = cycle;
        }
    }

    for (int i = cases.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      var tpCase = cases[i];

      if (tpCase.NextRenewalCycle == null)
      {
        cases.RemoveAt(i);
        continue;
      }

      //This is the time consuming part where all the requests are made
      var orderExist = db.OrderRows.Any(x =>
        x.BusinessSystemId == tpCase.BusinessSystemId &&
        x.CaseId == tpCase.CaseId &&
        x.Action == tpCase.NextRenewalCycle.Action &&
        x.Cycle == tpCase.NextRenewalCycle.Cycle
      );

      if (orderExist)
      {
        cases.RemoveAt(i);
      }
    }       
    return cases;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier than I first thought, I guess I had to write the question to see it.

Given that we have a FK to `TPRenewalCycle` in `OrderRow` I can just add `public virtual ICollection<OrderRow> OrderRows { get; set; }` to `TPRenewalCycle`.

In the query I can then include the order rows that match my given criteria like the other tables.

```
.Include(tpCase => tpCase.RenewalCycles.Select(renewalCycle => renewalCycle.OrderRows))
```

Now that I have this I can remove cases where next renewal cycle has any order rows. Since we already have the information no round trip is needed to the database and it goes really fast.

```
for (int i = cases.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  var tpCase = cases[i];

  if (tpCase.NextRenewalCycle == null || tpCase.NextRenewalCycle.OrderRows.Any())
  {
    cases.RemoveAt(i);
  }

}
```